# Is there a way to convert integer to a list of integers counting upwards?

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

Just say I have an integer in Python, ex: 100.

I'd like to convert this integer into a list counting up to this integer, ex: [1,2,3,... 100]

What is the most efficient way to do this?

(In case you're wondering why I want to do this, it's because the Django Paginate library I want to use needs a list -- if there's a more elegant way to use Paginate without doing this, please let me know).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python [`range()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range) does exactly what you want. E.g:

```
range(1, 101)
```

Note that `range()` counts from `0`, as is normal in Computer Science, so we need to pass `1`, and it counts until the given value, not including - hence `101` here to count to `100`. So generically, you want `range(1, n+1)` to count from `1` to `n`.

Also note that in 3.x, this produces an iterator, not a list, so if you need a list, then you can simply wrap `list()` around your call to `range()`. That said - most of the time it's possible to use an iterator rather than a list (which has large advantages, as iterators can be computed lazily), in that case, there is no need to make a list (in 2.x, functionality like that of range in 3.x can be achieved with [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by Lattyware is correct for generating the list, but if your using Django pagination you can just use `paginator_instance.page_range`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.page_range

Answer (score 1):

You can use range or xrange. xrange is faster, but returns an iterator.

```
>>>range(1,101)
[1, 2, 3, ... , 99, 100]

>>> xrange(1,101)
xrange(1, 101)

>>>list(xrange(1,101))
[1, 2, 3, ... , 99, 100]
```

Comment: Why use `xrange()` just to make it a list again?

Comment: Just showing as an example. Maybe a better example would have been "for a in xrange(1,101)".

Comment: @Lattyware on my machine at least, using the `timeit` module, `list(xrange(1,101))` is faster than `list(range(1,101))`

Comment: I would hope it would be! I was trying to give additional options. Although im not sure of the point of list(range(1,101)).

Comment: @frb Yes, but that comparison makes no sense. The right comparison is `list(xrange(...)` to `range(...)`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I've been in front of the computer too long today I think :)

Comment: @Ophion -- the point of `list(range(1,101))` would be python2.x and python3.x compatability in the case where you actually *need* a list.

Comment: @mgilson That doesn't really make much sense, as `2to3` will convert calls to `range(...)` to `list(range(...))` in 3.x.

Comment: @Lattyware It's sometimes useful to write programs that run in both Python2.x and Python3.x interpreters.

Comment: @frb That's a pretty limited audience - and I think if one is going to do that, one has to throw trying to get optimal performance out of the window, which was the initial comparison.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Yeah, I know.  But I've had other things which `2to3` didn't actually convert properly.  Maybe it's being stubborn or stupid, but wherever possible, and as long as it's not going to change the performance of my program much, I try to support python2 and python3 in the same source file without relying on external tools.  (usually it's not hard).